# Console, ctrl+c vs close button click

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7

When I click ctrl+c in a console window, event is raised and application can execute some piece of code which should be executed before exiting.

However, when I click [X] close button, event is raised too, but in a short time, my app I forcibly closed - when 'end execution' event is still in progress.

Is it possible to set longer timeout before windows will forcibly close app?

EDIT:

Im setting:

```
  [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
  static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ControlEventHandler e, bool add);

  public delegate void ControlEventHandler(ConsoleEvent consoleEvent);
```

When I click ctrl+c on console window, Im receiving: `CTRL_C`, and I can process code in mu event handler.

When I click [x] close button, I'm receiveing `CTRL_CLOSE` flag, I can process handler too, but only for 1-2secs. Then console windwo disappers...

Comment: Show your code please.  I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why are you using interop rather than: `Console.CancelKeyPress`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is not anything you can do to stop the user from closing the console window.  You get the callback to do something useful before the program terminates, that's all.  As soon as you return from the callback or take too long to do the useful thing then the OS steps in and kills the window.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: @AndyJ: I'm working on existing code (cannot change it, it's read-only repository).@HansPassant: so there is no option to change delay between [x] click and app termination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set longer timeout before windows will forcibly close app?

Unfortunately, no. Starting with Windows Vista, you are allowed only 10 seconds or so grace period after receiving the `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` before the console window automatically closes. If you haven't exited the handler by the time 10 seconds has elapsed, then your process is unceremoniously terminated. (Obviously, if you return from the handler sooner, you will not get the full 10 seconds.)

As far as I can tell, this is part of a larger design strategy to ensure that applications cannot override the will of the user. [Older versions of the SDK documentation](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32HandlerRoutine.htm) spoke of a dialog box that would appear if the process didn't respond within a certain time-out period, but all mention of that is gone from the [current version of the SDK documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242.aspx). The dialog box went MIA in Vista, it doesn't exist anymore. This is probably connected to the fact that applications can no longer block system shutdown either.

This doesn't affect your pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> because that raises a different signal—`CTRL_C_EVENT`. Same thing with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>, which raises `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`. But as far as I can tell from the documentation, `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`, and `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT` are simply *notifications*, giving you a chance to clean up before you are terminated. There is no way to block termination or extend the grace period.

There is only one workaround that I can think of, and that is to disable the close button on the console window itself. I see that you're using C#, so a bit of P/Invoke will be required:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

private const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x0;
private const uint SC_CLOSE     = 0xF060;

void DisableConsoleCloseButton()
{
    IntPtr hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        IntPtr hMenu = GetSystemMenu(hWnd, false);
        if (hMenu != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            DeleteMenu(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
        }
    }
}
```

If you go this route, you will obviously need to provide the user with some way of closing the console window from within your application. In Win32-land, that functionality would call the `FreeConsole` function to close it, but I'll bet that's wrapped up in one of the .NET classes. Been too long for me to remember what it's called.

Comment: Thanks. But for me, it takes like 3 seconds in handler, then app is terminated :/